# Changing -like '*uu-lillebaelt.dk*' to -like '*uuoresund.dk*' gives trouble

Tags: powershell, sql-like, exchange-server-2010

I have two near-identical Powershell scripts.

http://poshcode.org/4112

http://poshcode.org/4113

The only difference between the two is 2 places where uu-lillebaelt has been changed to uuoresund.
When I run the script with -like '*uuoresund*', I get a bunch of errors saying:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression
And this is happening when calling:

$size.IndexOf

$size.Substring

I have made sure, that size is not actually null, so that is not the problem.
I feel that it must be something about the -like operator I do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The Get-Mailbox on the domain also returned a DiscoverySearchMailbox that must be empty, or atleast return something that is not in a format. So to fix that, I just added a -notlike to get rid of that :)

Well, good thing it happened, otherwise I probably wouldn't have caught it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of $size when you encounter those errors? Print all mailboxes with their size to get a better view of those objects. In any case, If I may suggest a solution:

```
$totalSize = Get-Mailbox -Filter {WindowsEmailAddress -like "*$uucenter*"} | 
Get-MailboxStatistics | Foreach-Object {$_.TotalItemSize.Value} | 
Measure-Object -Sum | Foreach-Object {$_.Sum}
```

Comment: The type of $size is Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited<ByteQuantifiedSize>

An example could be: 210MB (210000000 bytes)
And this works correctly on the email domains uu-lillebaelt and uu-centersyd for. Only uuoresund gives trouble

Comment: I will try it, first thing tomorrow, busy with a meeting rest of the day ;-)

Comment: Using your example, I get no errors, but the in the resulting xml, totalSize is 0

Comment: Do you get any result with : Get-Mailbox -Filter {WindowsEmailAddress -like "*$uucenter*"} | 
Get-MailboxStatistics | Foreach-Object {$_.TotalItemSize.Value}

Comment: Found the problem, there was a pesky DiscoverySearchMailbox that is probably empty or return a different format :)